# Postgres database connection issue when using URL-special sensitive characters in the password

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, peewee

While attempting to connect to a PosgresQL database I got an authentication error. The issue turned out to be that Peewee's approach to parse the connection URL breaks when URL-special sensitive characters are used in the password e.g.

The following will not work with an authentication error:

```
from peewee import *
from playhouse.db_url import connect

url = "postgresql://host:port/database_name?user=username&password=123#456"
# or even
url = "postgresql://host:port/database_name?user=username&password=123%456"
db = connect(url)
```

However this will work:

```
from psycopg2 import connect

db = connect(url)
```

I am in a corporate setting so the passwords have strong requirements including the mandatory use of special characters. Is there a way to encode these characters so that they will work with `playhouse.db_url`'s connect implementation?

Comment: instead of using this format try `postgresql://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<database name>`

Comment: @sahasrara62 thank you, the issue is the same if I use this alternative URL form.

Comment: Have you tried [urlencoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) the query part of the url?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using pq for go and url encoding didn't work. Turns out the only characters you need to escape are `:` and `\` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html)

My string contained a `\` character which I replaced with `\\` and that solved the issue